# Create own validators with Typo3 8LTS SYSEXT:form

Tags: forms, yaml, typo3-8.x

For a long time I used EXT:formhandler for custom forms. In formhandler it was very easy to build custom validators like:
Checkbox "phone" is checked, then input-field phone is required.

Can someone show me an example of this custom validator with the new SYSEXT:form in Typo3 8LTS with SYSEXT:form?

Thanks a lot.